# How can I compare elements from two different arrays? Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a ruby def that looks like this:

```
def title_case(title, minor_words)

end
```

It's supposed to title case the string variable "title", any word in the minor_words variable is to be downcased and any word not it the minor_words variable is to be capitalized.

Example:

```
title_case("The King is a Good man", "a and the an at")

-> "the King Is a Good Man"
```

And the code I am attempting to write looks like this:

```
         def title_case(title, minor_words)
         title = title.downcase.split
         minor_words = minor_words.downcase.split
         title.map {|word| if word == (any word from minor_words)
        word.downcase 
        else 
         word.capitalize
         end}.join(" ")
         end
```

If minor_words is empty it returns title with all letters capitalized. Like so:

```
-> "The King Is A Good Man"
```

If title is empty, or both are empty it returns an empty string:

```
-> ""
```

Hope I made things clear! Thanks!

Comment: So, what would the result of this operation be for your example? Can you add some more examples that illustrate all the different rules, exceptions, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases? Can you specify the rules in a little more detail? What if one of the two arrays is empty? What if both are empty? Why do you capitalize the word in your code, when there is no mention of capitalization in the problem statement? Why do you concatenate the words in your code, when there is no mention of concatenation in the problem statement?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a ternary statement:

```rb
ary1.map { |e| ary2.include?(e.downcase) ? e.downcase : e }
# => ["the", "man", "is", "not", "nice"]
```

To mutate the array in place use `Array#map!` instead of `Array#map`.

Comment: @engineersmnky: The question was completely rewritten *after* this answer was submitted. The original question had *two* arrays `ary1` and `ary2`. Now, the question has only *one* array and an additional string that didn't exist in the original version of the question. You can't really fault an answerer if the question asker completely changes the question after an answer is posted. The original question was something like "how can I downcase any string in `ary1` that appears in `ary2`".